# Reading TarArchiveEntry file from Worker Thread is Blocking IO Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe, blocking, quarkus

I am sending a tar.gz file in a post request to a Quarkus endpoint, and I want to extract the tar and upload its contents to a database.  I want to keep memory overhead low, so I am streaming the tar instead of saving it.  I am able to get each TarArchiveEntry and print its name.  I am using piped streams to read bytes into a vertx worker thread.  However, when I try to read the contents of a TarArchiveEntry, the event thread is being blocked indefinitely.  The program just comes to a halt.  I've tried adding buffered streams, but with no success.

Why is reading the file (or stream) from a worker thread blocking the IO thread?

Here is the stack trace:

```
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.base@11/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base@11/java.io.PipedInputStream.awaitSpace(PipedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.base@11/java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:231)
    at java.base@11/java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:149)
    at java.base@11/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:122)
```

```java
 router.post("/upload").handler(rc -> {

            final PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream pipeIn = null;
            try {
                pipeIn = new PipedInputStream(pipeOut);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final PipedInputStream pin = pipeIn;

            rc.request().handler( body -> {
                try {
                    pipeOut.write(body.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
                try {
                    TarArchiveInputStream tar = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(pin));
                    TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
                    while ((entry = tar.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                        String entryName = entry.getName();
                        if (entryName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                            System.out.println("txt found: " + entryName);
                            File file = entry.getFile();
                            System.out.println("File acquired!");
                            // file.isFile() is causing the main thread to be blocked
                            // Doing any kind of reading the file is causing the main thread to be blocked
                            if(file.isFile())
                                System.out.println("This is indeed a file!");

                        } else if (entryName.endsWith(".csv")) {
                            System.out.println("CSV found: " + entryName);
                        } else if (entryName.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                            System.out.println("JPG found: " + entryName);
                        } else if(entryName.endsWith(".wav")){
                            System.out.println("WAV found: " + entryName);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                future.complete();
            }, res -> {
                //TODO
            });
```

Comment: Could you create a reproducer and create an issue on our tracker? Thanks!